# Probability of Patients Being Well

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Consider a simple model that progresses year-by-year. In year $i$, let $W_i$ = patient is well, $I_i$ = patient is ill, and $D_i$ = patient is dead. Transitions can be modeled as a set of conditional probabilities.

Let $L$ = number of years that the patient is well.

I have come up with the probability mass function of L to be $P(L=\ell)=(p)^{\ell-1}(1-p)$.

The next part of the problem is to consider the following scenario: 100 patients were all well in year 1 and the probability of being well in year 3 is estimated to be 80%. Assuming the transition probabilities are constant, what is $P(W_{i+1}|W_i)$?

My assumption was that I would plug in the information given from the studies. For example, for study 1: $P(L=3)=0.8=(p)^{2}(1-p)$ and then solve for $p$. However, according to Wolfram Alpha, this should result in $p=-6.88365$ which doesn't make sense for a probability value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first of all for solving your equation $p^2(1-p)\leqslant p(1-p)\leqslant1/4$, so this can't be solved. Assuming the transition probabilities are the same gives:
$$
0.8=p(W_3|W_1)=p(W_2|W_1)p(W_3|W_2)=p(W_2|W_1)^2.
$$
This is saying that for a patient to be well in year 3, given that they were well in year 1, they can't get ill in year 2.

So, we have
$$
p(W_{i+1}|W_i)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}.
$$

I'm a bit confused by the two studies, they seem to be word for word the same?

Comment: Thanks that makes more sense than what I was doing. Also, study 2 was supposed to be L=7 and 40%. I seem to have forgotten to edit after copy/pasting. I'm assuming that the work is similar to what was done here.

Comment: `yep, that's right

Comment: Follow on question. I notice that on average, 10 patients become unwell per year in both studies, but the calculated P(W_{i+1}|W_i) values are different for each study. Does this have to do with the fact that the studies take place over different time periods, so more/less patients can fall unwell in earlier/later years? That is they have static P acting on a different number of patients per year?

Comment: Yes. If after some time there are 50 well patients left, 10 patients becoming unwell is 20%.